# JQuery $.get and inflate data

Tags: jquery, pako

I was handed over a small browser application which fetches a binary file, unpacks it and then shows it's content in the browser.

I'm however not able to convert the data correctly into a byte array, and subsequently inflation fails with "invalid code length set".

This is my get method:

```
$.get("metafile.hsm", function (metaFile) {
    readCellFile(metaFile);
});
```

And this is the method inflating the file:

```
  function readCellFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    //      var file = document.getElementById('cell_file_input').files[0];
    reader.onload = function() { 
      var compressedData = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
      var data        = pako.inflate(compressedData); // Error "Invalid code length set"
      var buf = new flatbuffers.ByteBuffer(data);
      var cell = hdm.storage.hsg.Cell.getRootAsCell(buf);
      var features = parseCell(cell);
      // ...

    }

    reader.onerror = function(event) {
      console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
    };

    var blob = new Blob([file], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  }
```

Am I doing the conversion wrong? I can rule out that the file is broken, as you can see in the commented out line I was testing to upload the file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if gzipping within Javascript is really necessary for your goal. If the server is configured to support gzipping files and the browser supports gzipping then files (even those requested through javascript) should be compressed automatically.

If you need to go with this approach (for example because you have no control over the server) then it's probably better to fetch the file from within a web worker and do the unzipping there as well. The following code (tested working on chrome with a gzipped text file) assumes you have pako_inflate.min.js in the same directory as the main script and the worker. Also note if testing locally your browser may block loading the web worker from a local file for security reasons.

Simply call loadFile passing the name of the file you want to load. onFileLoaded will be called with the data once it's finished loading.

**fileLoader.js**

```
/*
* If you are running this locally your browser may block you from 
* loading web worker from a local file. For testing you may want to run 
* a simple local web server like so: 'python -m http.server 8000'
*/
var gzippedFileLoaderWorker = new Worker("gzippedFileLoaderWorker.js");

gzippedFileLoaderWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
    var message = event.data;
    if (message.type == "START") {  
        console.log(message.data);
    } else if (message.type == "END") {
        onFileLoaded(message.data);         
    } else if (message.type == "ERROR") { 
        console.log(message.data); 
    }
};

function loadFile(fileName) {
    gzippedFileLoaderWorker.postMessage({ 
        type: 'loadFile', 
        fileName: fileName 
    }); 
}

function onFileLoaded(uncompressedFileData) {
    console.log("Data Loaded:" + uncompressedFileData);
}
```

**gzippedFileLoaderWorker.js**

```
importScripts('pako_inflate.min.js');

onmessage = function(event) {
  var message = event.data;
  if (message.type === "loadFile") {
    postMessage({ 
        'type' : 'START', 
        'data' : "Started Downloading: " + message.fileName 
    });
    try {
        /* 
        * Fetch is not supported on ie yet. If this is a requirement 
        * find a polyfill like whatwg-fetch 
        */
        fetch(message.fileName).then(function(response) {
            if (!response["ok"]) { 
                postMessage({ 
                    'type' : 'ERROR', 
                    'data' : "Error loading: " + message.fileName 
               })       
            }
            return response["arrayBuffer"](); 
        }).then(function(zipped) { 
            return pako.ungzip(new Uint8Array(zipped));
        }).then(function(binary) { 
            /* 
            *  Do any processing on the binary data here so you don't
            *  block the main thread! Then pass that data back as an
            *  object instead of the binary in the post message
            */
            postMessage({ 
                'type' : 'END', 
                'data' : binary 
            });
        }); 
    } catch(err) {
        postMessage({ 
            'type' : 'ERROR', 
            'data' : err.message 
        });
    }
  }
}
```